# Bootstrap Datepicker Selected date reset

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I need to reset the selected date of the date picker every time the date picker is shown, but I am unable to do so. If select a previous date. The date gets selected. Then if I try to select a date again, I want that the previous date should be selected anymore.

Comment: What library are you using for the datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on GitHub, I don't know if you are using that datepicker though

[DatePicker Help](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Look at the Enable and Disabled dates that should do the trick.